# How can I save/load App Designer app object in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am creating an app which starts by creating a large Gridlayout (60,16) that contain two columns of UIButtons and the rest is UITextare. I am using a button to create the gridlayout (function CreateGridButtonPushed(app, event) in the below code). However, the grid takes 84.298651 seconds, which to me is a very long time. It seems like the grid is re-drawn sequentially for every new UIelement in the cell.

- Is there a way I can speed this up?

Alternative, I tried to save the Gridlayout as a *.mat file (function SaveGridButtonPushed(app, event) in the below code) and then instead of creating the grid from scratch I want to simply load the Gridlayout object and copy it to app.Gridlayout when I click the button. But I get this error: ***Warning: Unable to save App Designer app object. Save not supported for matlab.apps.AppBase objects***.

- Is there a way I can save/load a matlab.apps.AppBase object?

The code I am using is below.

```
properties (Access = public)
        GridLayout
        %set handle on every uielement in the Gridlayout for later being able to change background color on selected elements
        uit01_1; uib02_1; uib03_1; uit04_1; uit05_1,uit06_1; uit07_1; uit08_1,uit09_1; uit10_1; uit11_1; uit12_1; uit13_1; uit14_1; uit15_1; uit16_1;
        uit01_2; uib02_2; uib03_2; uit04_2; uit05_2,uit06_2; uit07_2; uit08_2,uit09_2; uit10_2; uit11_2; uit12_2; uit13_2; uit14_2; uit15_2; uit16_2;
        uit01_3; uib02_3; uib03_3; uit04_3; uit05_3,uit06_3; uit07_3; uit08_3,uit09_3; uit10_3; uit11_3; uit12_3; uit13_3; uit14_3; uit15_3; uit16_3;
        uit01_4; uib02_4; uib03_4; uit04_4; uit05_4,uit06_4; uit07_4; uit08_4,uit09_4; uit10_4; uit11_4; uit12_4; uit13_4; uit14_4; uit15_4; uit16_4;
        uit01_5; uib02_5; uib03_5; uit04_5; uit05_5,uit06_5; uit07_5; uit08_5,uit09_5; uit10_5; uit11_5; uit12_5; uit13_5; uit14_5; uit15_5; uit16_5;
        uit01_6; uib02_6; uib03_6; uit04_6; uit05_6,uit06_6; uit07_6; uit08_6,uit09_6; uit10_6; uit11_6; uit12_6; uit13_6; uit14_6; uit15_6; uit16_6;
        uit01_7; uib02_7; uib03_7; uit04_7; uit05_7,uit06_7; uit07_7; uit08_7,uit09_7; uit10_7; uit11_7; uit12_7; uit13_7; uit14_7; uit15_7; uit16_7;
        uit01_8; uib02_8; uib03_8; uit04_8; uit05_8,uit06_8; uit07_8; uit08_8,uit09_8; uit10_8; uit11_8; uit12_8; uit13_8; uit14_8; uit15_8; uit16_8;
        uit01_9; uib02_9; uib03_9; uit04_9; uit05_9,uit06_9; uit07_9; uit08_9,uit09_9; uit10_9; uit11_9; uit12_9; uit13_9; uit14_9; uit15_9; uit16_9;
        uit01_10; uib02_10; uib03_10; uit04_10; uit05_10,uit06_10; uit07_10; uit08_10,uit09_10; uit10_10; uit11_10; uit12_10; uit13_10; uit14_10; uit15_10; uit16_10;
        uit01_11; uib02_11; uib03_11; uit04_11; uit05_11,uit06_11; uit07_11; uit08_11,uit09_11; uit10_11; uit11_11; uit12_11; uit13_11; uit14_11; uit15_11; uit16_11;
        uit01_12; uib02_12; uib03_12; uit04_12; uit05_12,uit06_12; uit07_12; uit08_12,uit09_12; uit10_12; uit11_12; uit12_12; uit13_12; uit14_12; uit15_12; uit16_12;
        uit01_13; uib02_13; uib03_13; uit04_13; uit05_13,uit06_13; uit07_13; uit08_13,uit09_13; uit10_13; uit11_13; uit12_13; uit13_13; uit14_13; uit15_13; uit16_13;
        uit01_14; uib02_14; uib03_14; uit04_14; uit05_14,uit06_14; uit07_14; uit08_14,uit09_14; uit10_14; uit11_14; uit12_14; uit13_14; uit14_14; uit15_14; uit16_14;
        uit01_15; uib02_15; uib03_15; uit04_15; uit05_15,uit06_15; uit07_15; uit08_15,uit09_15; uit10_15; uit11_15; uit12_15; uit13_15; uit14_15; uit15_15; uit16_15;
        uit01_16; uib02_16; uib03_16; uit04_16; uit05_16,uit06_16; uit07_16; uit08_16,uit09_16; uit10_16; uit11_16; uit12_16; uit13_16; uit14_16; uit15_16; uit16_16;
        uit01_17; uib02_17; uib03_17; uit04_17; uit05_17,uit06_17; uit07_17; uit08_17,uit09_17; uit10_17; uit11_17; uit12_17; uit13_17; uit14_17; uit15_17; uit16_17;
        uit01_18; uib02_18; uib03_18; uit04_18; uit05_18,uit06_18; uit07_18; uit08_18,uit09_18; uit10_18; uit11_18; uit12_18; uit13_18; uit14_18; uit15_18; uit16_18;
        uit01_19; uib02_19; uib03_19; uit04_19; uit05_19,uit06_19; uit07_19; uit08_19,uit09_19; uit10_19; uit11_19; uit12_19; uit13_19; uit14_19; uit15_19; uit16_19;
        uit01_20; uib02_20; uib03_20; uit04_20; uit05_20,uit06_20; uit07_20; uit08_20,uit09_20; uit10_20; uit11_20; uit12_20; uit13_20; uit14_20; uit15_20; uit16_20;
        uit01_21; uib02_21; uib03_21; uit04_21; uit05_21,uit06_21; uit07_21; uit08_21,uit09_21; uit10_21; uit11_21; uit12_21; uit13_21; uit14_21; uit15_21; uit16_21;
        uit01_22; uib02_22; uib03_22; uit04_22; uit05_22,uit06_22; uit07_22; uit08_22,uit09_22; uit10_22; uit11_22; uit12_22; uit13_22; uit14_22; uit15_22; uit16_22;
        uit01_23; uib02_23; uib03_23; uit04_23; uit05_23,uit06_23; uit07_23; uit08_23,uit09_23; uit10_23; uit11_23; uit12_23; uit13_23; uit14_23; uit15_23; uit16_23;
        uit01_24; uib02_24; uib03_24; uit04_24; uit05_24,uit06_24; uit07_24; uit08_24,uit09_24; uit10_24; uit11_24; uit12_24; uit13_24; uit14_24; uit15_24; uit16_24;
        uit01_25; uib02_25; uib03_25; uit04_25; uit05_25,uit06_25; uit07_25; uit08_25,uit09_25; uit10_25; uit11_25; uit12_25; uit13_25; uit14_25; uit15_25; uit16_25;
        uit01_26; uib02_26; uib03_26; uit04_26; uit05_26,uit06_26; uit07_26; uit08_26,uit09_26; uit10_26; uit11_26; uit12_26; uit13_26; uit14_26; uit15_26; uit16_26;
        uit01_27; uib02_27; uib03_27; uit04_27; uit05_27,uit06_27; uit07_27; uit08_27,uit09_27; uit10_27; uit11_27; uit12_27; uit13_27; uit14_27; uit15_27; uit16_27;
        uit01_28; uib02_28; uib03_28; uit04_28; uit05_28,uit06_28; uit07_28; uit08_28,uit09_28; uit10_28; uit11_28; uit12_28; uit13_28; uit14_28; uit15_28; uit16_28;
        uit01_29; uib02_29; uib03_29; uit04_29; uit05_29,uit06_29; uit07_29; uit08_29,uit09_29; uit10_29; uit11_29; uit12_29; uit13_29; uit14_29; uit15_29; uit16_29;
        uit01_30; uib02_30; uib03_30; uit04_30; uit05_30,uit06_30; uit07_30; uit08_30,uit09_30; uit10_30; uit11_30; uit12_30; uit13_30; uit14_30; uit15_30; uit16_30;        
        uit01_31; uib02_31; uib03_31; uit04_31; uit05_31,uit06_31; uit07_31; uit08_31,uit09_31; uit10_31; uit11_31; uit12_31; uit13_31; uit14_31; uit15_31; uit16_31;
        uit01_32; uib02_32; uib03_32; uit04_32; uit05_32,uit06_32; uit07_32; uit08_32,uit09_32; uit10_32; uit11_32; uit12_32; uit13_32; uit14_32; uit15_32; uit16_32;
        uit01_33; uib02_33; uib03_33; uit04_33; uit05_33,uit06_33; uit07_33; uit08_33,uit09_33; uit10_33; uit11_33; uit12_33; uit13_33; uit14_33; uit15_33; uit16_33;
        uit01_34; uib02_34; uib03_34; uit04_34; uit05_34,uit06_34; uit07_34; uit08_34,uit09_34; uit10_34; uit11_34; uit12_34; uit13_34; uit14_34; uit15_34; uit16_34;
        uit01_35; uib02_35; uib03_35; uit04_35; uit05_35,uit06_35; uit07_35; uit08_35,uit09_35; uit10_35; uit11_35; uit12_35; uit13_35; uit14_35; uit15_35; uit16_35;
        uit01_36; uib02_36; uib03_36; uit04_36; uit05_36,uit06_36; uit07_36; uit08_36,uit09_36; uit10_36; uit11_36; uit12_36; uit13_36; uit14_36; uit15_36; uit16_36;
        uit01_37; uib02_37; uib03_37; uit04_37; uit05_37,uit06_37; uit07_37; uit08_37,uit09_37; uit10_37; uit11_37; uit12_37; uit13_37; uit14_37; uit15_37; uit16_37;
        uit01_38; uib02_38; uib03_38; uit04_38; uit05_38,uit06_38; uit07_38; uit08_38,uit09_38; uit10_38; uit11_38; uit12_38; uit13_38; uit14_38; uit15_38; uit16_38;
        uit01_39; uib02_39; uib03_39; uit04_39; uit05_39,uit06_39; uit07_39; uit08_39,uit09_39; uit10_39; uit11_39; uit12_39; uit13_39; uit14_39; uit15_39; uit16_39;
        uit01_40; uib02_40; uib03_40; uit04_40; uit05_40,uit06_40; uit07_40; uit08_40,uit09_40; uit10_40; uit11_40; uit12_40; uit13_40; uit14_40; uit15_40; uit16_40;       
        uit01_41; uib02_41; uib03_41; uit04_41; uit05_41,uit06_41; uit07_41; uit08_41,uit09_41; uit10_41; uit11_41; uit12_41; uit13_41; uit14_41; uit15_41; uit16_41;
        uit01_42; uib02_42; uib03_42; uit04_42; uit05_42,uit06_42; uit07_42; uit08_42,uit09_42; uit10_42; uit11_42; uit12_42; uit13_42; uit14_42; uit15_42; uit16_42;
        uit01_43; uib02_43; uib03_43; uit04_43; uit05_43,uit06_43; uit07_43; uit08_43,uit09_43; uit10_43; uit11_43; uit12_43; uit13_43; uit14_43; uit15_43; uit16_43;
        uit01_44; uib02_44; uib03_44; uit04_44; uit05_44,uit06_44; uit07_44; uit08_44,uit09_44; uit10_44; uit11_44; uit12_44; uit13_44; uit14_44; uit15_44; uit16_44;
        uit01_45; uib02_45; uib03_45; uit04_45; uit05_45,uit06_45; uit07_45; uit08_45,uit09_45; uit10_45; uit11_45; uit12_45; uit13_45; uit14_45; uit15_45; uit16_45;
        uit01_46; uib02_46; uib03_46; uit04_46; uit05_46,uit06_46; uit07_46; uit08_46,uit09_46; uit10_46; uit11_46; uit12_46; uit13_46; uit14_46; uit15_46; uit16_46;
        uit01_47; uib02_47; uib03_47; uit04_47; uit05_47,uit06_47; uit07_47; uit08_47,uit09_47; uit10_47; uit11_47; uit12_47; uit13_47; uit14_47; uit15_47; uit16_47;
        uit01_48; uib02_48; uib03_48; uit04_48; uit05_48,uit06_48; uit07_48; uit08_48,uit09_48; uit10_48; uit11_48; uit12_48; uit13_48; uit14_48; uit15_48; uit16_48;
        uit01_49; uib02_49; uib03_49; uit04_49; uit05_49,uit06_49; uit07_49; uit08_49,uit09_49; uit10_49; uit11_49; uit12_49; uit13_49; uit14_49; uit15_49; uit16_49;
        uit01_50; uib02_50; uib03_50; uit04_50; uit05_50,uit06_50; uit07_50; uit08_50,uit09_50; uit10_50; uit11_50; uit12_50; uit13_50; uit14_50; uit15_50; uit16_50;        
        uit01_51; uib02_51; uib03_51; uit04_51; uit05_51,uit06_51; uit07_51; uit08_51,uit09_51; uit10_51; uit11_51; uit12_51; uit13_51; uit14_51; uit15_51; uit16_51;
        uit01_52; uib02_52; uib03_52; uit04_52; uit05_52,uit06_52; uit07_52; uit08_52,uit09_52; uit10_52; uit11_52; uit12_52; uit13_52; uit14_52; uit15_52; uit16_52;
        uit01_53; uib02_53; uib03_53; uit04_53; uit05_53,uit06_53; uit07_53; uit08_53,uit09_53; uit10_53; uit11_53; uit12_53; uit13_53; uit14_53; uit15_53; uit16_53;
        uit01_54; uib02_54; uib03_54; uit04_54; uit05_54,uit06_54; uit07_54; uit08_54,uit09_54; uit10_54; uit11_54; uit12_54; uit13_54; uit14_54; uit15_54; uit16_54;
        uit01_55; uib02_55; uib03_55; uit04_55; uit05_55,uit06_55; uit07_55; uit08_55,uit09_55; uit10_55; uit11_55; uit12_55; uit13_55; uit14_55; uit15_55; uit16_55;
        uit01_56; uib02_56; uib03_56; uit04_56; uit05_56,uit06_56; uit07_56; uit08_56,uit09_56; uit10_56; uit11_56; uit12_56; uit13_56; uit14_56; uit15_56; uit16_56;
        uit01_57; uib02_57; uib03_57; uit04_57; uit05_57,uit06_57; uit07_57; uit08_57,uit09_57; uit10_57; uit11_57; uit12_57; uit13_57; uit14_57; uit15_57; uit16_57;
        uit01_58; uib02_58; uib03_58; uit04_58; uit05_58,uit06_58; uit07_58; uit08_58,uit09_58; uit10_58; uit11_58; uit12_58; uit13_58; uit14_58; uit15_58; uit16_58;
        uit01_59; uib02_59; uib03_59; uit04_59; uit05_59,uit06_59; uit07_59; uit08_59,uit09_59; uit10_59; uit11_59; uit12_59; uit13_59; uit14_59; uit15_59; uit16_59;
        uit01_60; uib02_60; uib03_60; uit04_60; uit05_60,uit06_60; uit07_60; uit08_60,uit09_60; uit10_60; uit11_60; uit12_60; uit13_60; uit14_60; uit15_60; uit16_60;
    end
    
    methods (Access = private)
        % Create the function for the Name ButtonPushedFcn callback
        function uibNameButtonPushed(app,btn)
            disp(strcat(num2str(btn.Layout.Row),' ',num2str(btn.Layout.Column)))
        end
        
        % Create the function for the Name ButtonPushedFcn callback
        function uibNameButtonPushed2(app,btn2)
            disp(strcat(num2str(btn2.Layout.Row),' ',num2str(btn2.Layout.Column)))
        end
        end
```

New button function

```
% Button pushed function: CreateGridButton
        function CreateGridButtonPushed(app, event)
           tic
            
            %Create gridlayout
            testSize = 20;
            app.GridLayout = uigridlayout(app.Panel2,[testSize 16],'Scrollable','on');
            
            %Set app.grid properties
            app.GridLayout.Visible = 'off';
            app.GridLayout.ColumnSpacing = 0;
            app.GridLayout.RowSpacing = 0;
            app.GridLayout.RowHeight = 45;
            app.GridLayout.ColumnWidth = {100,25,100,35,35,35,35,'1x','1x','1x','1x','1x',230,110,65,50};
            %Standard Colorcodes
            Headercolor = [0.4 0.4 0.4];
            cellcolor = [0.5 0 0];
            buttoncolor = [0.9 0.9 0.9];
            
            % Create UI elements in app.GridLayout. The first row is a header the second contain buttons 
            app.uit01_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit01_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit01_1.Layout.Column = 1;
            app.uit01_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uib02_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uib02_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uib02_1.Layout.Column = 2;
            app.uib02_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uib03_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uib03_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uib03_1.Layout.Column = 3;
            app.uib03_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit04_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit04_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit04_1.Layout.Column = 4;
            app.uit04_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit05_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout); 
            app.uit05_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit05_1.Layout.Column = 5;
            app.uit05_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit06_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit06_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit06_1.Layout.Column = 6;
            app.uit06_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit07_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit07_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit07_1.Layout.Column = 7;
            app.uit07_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit08_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit08_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit08_1.Layout.Column = 8;
            app.uit08_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit09_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit09_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit09_1.Layout.Column = 9;
            app.uit09_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit10_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit10_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit10_1.Layout.Column = 10;
            app.uit10_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit11_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit11_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit11_1.Layout.Column = 11;
            app.uit11_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit12_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit12_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit12_1.Layout.Column = 12;
            app.uit12_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit13_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout); 
            app.uit13_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit13_1.Layout.Column = 13;
            app.uit13_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit14_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout); 
            app.uit14_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit14_1.Layout.Column = 14;
            app.uit14_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit15_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
            app.uit15_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit15_1.Layout.Column = 15;
            app.uit15_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            app.uit16_1 = uitextarea(app.GridLayout); 
            app.uit16_1.Layout.Row = 1;
            app.uit16_1.Layout.Column = 16;
            app.uit16_1.BackgroundColor = Headercolor;
            
            for h = 2:testSize
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit01_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit01_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit01_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 1;
                app.(sprintf('uit01_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
            
                % Create Button
                app.(sprintf('uib02_%d', h)) = uibutton(app.GridLayout,'Text','TEST','ButtonPushedFcn', @(btn,event) uibNameButtonPushed(app,btn));
                app.(sprintf('uib02_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uib02_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 2;
                app.(sprintf('uib02_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = buttoncolor;
                            
                % Create Button
                app.(sprintf('uib03_%d', h)) = uibutton(app.GridLayout,'Text','TEST2','ButtonPushedFcn', @(btn2,event) uibNameButtonPushed2(app,btn2));
                app.(sprintf('uib03_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uib03_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 3;
                app.(sprintf('uib03_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = buttoncolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit04_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit04_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit04_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 4;
                app.(sprintf('uit04_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit05_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit05_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit05_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 5;
                app.(sprintf('uit05_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit06_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit06_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit06_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 6;
                app.(sprintf('uit06_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit07_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit07_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit07_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 7;
                app.(sprintf('uit07_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit08_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit08_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit08_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 8;
                app.(sprintf('uit08_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit09_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit09_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit09_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 9;
                app.(sprintf('uit09_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit10_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit10_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit10_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 10;
                app.(sprintf('uit10_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit11_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit11_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit11_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 11;
                app.(sprintf('uit11_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit12_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit12_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit12_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 12;
                app.(sprintf('uit12_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit13_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit13_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit13_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 13;
                app.(sprintf('uit13_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit14_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit14_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit14_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 14;
                app.(sprintf('uit14_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit15_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit15_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit15_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 15;
                app.(sprintf('uit15_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
                
                % Create TextArea
                app.(sprintf('uit16_%d', h)) = uitextarea(app.GridLayout);
                app.(sprintf('uit16_%d', h)).Layout.Row = h;
                app.(sprintf('uit16_%d', h)).Layout.Column = 16;
                app.(sprintf('uit16_%d', h)).BackgroundColor = cellcolor;
            end
            
            app.GridLayout.Visible = 'on';
            
            toc
        end
```

New button function

```
        % Button pushed function: SaveGridButton
        function SaveGridButtonPushed(app, event)
            Grid = app.GridLayout;
            save('Grid.mat','Grid');
        end
```

New button function

```
        % Button pushed function: LoadGridButton
        function LoadGridButtonPushed(app, event)
            test = load('Panel.mat');
            app.GridLayout = test.Grid;            
        end
```